# exclude element by tag with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filtering

How to exclude specific elements with jquery selector? With this example, I can add as many water and seeds in any orders, but when I click the sun button, all of the water should be disappeared, but the seed should remain. When I click the moon button, the water should appear again while seed untouched.  I try to filter out any element with 'span' tag. I tried .not('span') function, but not succeeding. How can I exclude elements contains 'span' tag with jquery selector? TIA

```js
$("#water").click(function(){$("#garden").append('<div>water</div>');});
$("#seed").click(function(){$("#garden").append('<span><div>seed</div></span>');});
$("#sun").click(function(){$("#garden div").not('span').addClass('vapor');});
$("#moon").click(function(){$("#garden div").not('span').removeClass('vapor');});
```

```css
div.vapor{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='water'>water</button>
<button id='seed'>seed</button>
<button id='sun'>sun</button>
<button id='moon'>moon</button>
<div id='garden'></div>
```

Here is a second example to why it has to be tag instead of using class. Notice I used 'select' and 'option' in this example and using CSS to hide option is not fully supported by browsers. My problem with this example is that if I click on 'sun' button 10 times, I have to click 'moon' buttons 10 times for the water to show. I need to use tag exclusion on 'sun' button so that it doesn't wrap 'span' on 'water' option more than once. What I want to achieve is no matter how many times I clicked 'sun' button, I only need to click moon button once, and the water appears again. Thank you

```js
$("#water").click(function(){$("#garden").append('<option class="water">water</option>');});
$("#seed").click(function(){$("#garden").append('<option>seed</option>');});
$("#sun").click(function(){$("#garden option.water").wrap('<span>');});
$("#moon").click(function(){$("#garden span option.water").unwrap();});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='water'>water</button>
<button id='seed'>seed</button>
<button id='sun'>sun</button>
<button id='moon'>moon</button>
<select id='garden'><option></option></select>
```

Comment: It's be much easier to solve your problem if the water and seeds you appended had their own classes

Comment: @j08691, yes, I understand that totally, But in some case, using class is not practical for browser compatibility, and using tag is needed. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: _"using class is not practical for browser compatibility, and using tag is needed"_ I don't think in all my years of coding I've ever heard or experienced that

Comment: @j08691 I put a second example for you to demonstrate why sometimes class is not practical for browser compatibility and tag is needed. For the best way to hide some options within select is to wrap it with a tag, for browsers compatibility. I still need to exclude 'span' tag to avoid 'sun' button execute more than once when it is clicked many times. I could be wrong, but I hope you could understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have a solution, I found my own solutions after days of struggle. The key is using '>' in the selector. I applied '>' to both of my examples and both work. Again, I am not going to vote for my own answer even it works, in order to promote other elegant solutions. Thanks anyway.

```js
//example 1
$("#water1").click(function(){$("#garden1").append('<div>water</div>');});
$("#seed1").click(function(){$("#garden1").append('<span><div>seed</div></span>');});
$("#sun1").click(function(){$("#garden1>div").addClass('vapor');});
$("#moon1").click(function(){$("#garden1 div").removeClass('vapor');});

//example2
$("#water2").click(function(){$("#garden2").append('<option class="water2">water</option>');});
$("#seed2").click(function(){$("#garden2").append('<option>seed</option>');});
$("#sun2").click(function(){$("#garden2>option.water2").wrap('<span>');});
$("#moon2").click(function(){$("#garden2 span option.water2").unwrap();});
```

```css
div.vapor{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>example 1</h4>
<button id='water1'>water</button>
<button id='seed1'>seed</button>
<button id='sun1'>sun</button>
<button id='moon1'>moon</button>
<div id='garden1'></div>

<h4>example 2</h4>
<button id='water2'>water</button>
<button id='seed2'>seed</button>
<button id='sun2'>sun</button>
<button id='moon2'>moon</button>
<select id='garden2'><option></option></select>
```